# What kind of filters can be used for filtering high amplitude signals?

Tags: active-filter, passive-filter

I want to build a filter that only allows signals with big enough amplitude to pass. Where should I start?

Comment: Please add more specifications, this is too broad to go on. Hints: is your signal digital or analog? if it's analog, how do you expect your signal to look like? What if your signal goes below your theshold? please sketch as waveforms your input and output of what you expect.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! All of my signals are analog sine shape signals. Some might have glitches. I want the filter to stop the signals below threshold. For example I have a 1 HZ 8V sin signal and a 6 HZ 1V sin signal, if I input them to filter, I want  to only output the 1hz 8V signal.

Comment: Are your signals fixed (i.e. predictable) in amplitude? or do they also vary amplitude in time?

Comment: To be clear, we don't call that function a "filter".  Some manner of schmitt trigger seems like what you want.  Possibly with adaptive thresholds, if the inputs can have varying amplitudes and you want to track whichever one is strongest.  Indeterminate behavior will occur when they are of similar amplitudes.

Comment: Hi @ErnestoG, all of my signals have fixed amplitudes.

Comment: ["Dead-band"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadband#:~:text=A%20deadband%20or%20dead%2Dband,'%20%2D%20no%20action%20occurs). is the control system function that does this.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi, thank you for your response! I will look into schmitt triggers.

Comment: You might need to specify your problem better. We don't call that a filter. The reason we do not is that a sine-wave of amplitude A includes values from -A to zero, and from zero to A. That there's no real-time criteria that you can use to filter. It's more like like looking at a signal and then passing or rejecting the entire signal after-the-fact rather than filtering parts of the signal out of each other.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include all the details of your signal(s). That info belongs up there, not down in the comments.

Comment: If the input signal is of known structure then the simplest way might be just to read the signal analyze it, and if it matches your criteria through correlation or whatever, to just reproduce. But if you have variations that you want to pass in your signal things gets more complicated (like needing to buffer the signal and then analyzing it and then passing that stored signal through). What are you actually trying to do? Because there is a high probability you are approaching things in the wrong way.

Comment: Useful search term : noise gate. Or in radio, squelch control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One device that does this is called a [noise gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_gate). It is used to mute a signal until the level reaches a threshold, and then pass the signal. It's commonly used in audio processing such as guitar effects to block low level noise when there is no useful signal.

The way it is done is to sample the input, derive a DC voltage from it representing it's level, and use that with a comparator to control electronic switches that either mute the signal or pass it to the output. The reference level to the comparator is variable to allow the cutoff level to be set just above the noise level.

If you only want to process one signal at a time this should work. If the signal is strong enough it will let it through, if not it blocks it, but for multiple signals at the same time it wouldn't be able to select just one and reject the others, it's all-or-nothing.

If you want to pick one signal out of several based solely on their levels you might be able to do it with digital signal processing (DSP).